# Nested call don't trigger interceptors

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, aop, interceptor

I want to attach interceptor to a few methods, from which one of them might call other intercepted methods, only the fist interceptor is run. How can I get this to work:

```
class A : IWorker
{
    int Method1()
    {
        return 2*Method2();
    }

    int Method2()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Interceptor implementation

```
public class WorkerUsageLogger : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var indent = new string('\t', tabs);
        Console.WriteLine($"{indent}Calling method {invocation.Method.Name}.");
        tabs++;
        invocation.Proceed();
        tabs--;
        Console.WriteLine($"{indent}Completed method {invocation.Method.Name}");
    }
}
```

attaching interceptor

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(new WorkerUsageLogger());
builder.RegisterType<A>().As<IWorker>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(WorkerUsageLogger));
var container = builder.Build();
IWorker worker = container.Resolve<IWorker>();
```

On calling

```
worker.Method1();
```

I'm expecting:

```
"Calling method Method1"
    "Calling method Method2"
    "Completed method Method2"
"Completed method Method1"
```

I'm getting

```
"Calling method Method1"
"Completed method Method1"
```

Comment: What recursive call? I don't see any in the posted code

Comment: How is the interceptor attached to the class? What are you seeing working? What are you expecting? What have you tried? (Update the question, don't answer in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor returns an object of type `IWorker`, which has code to go through your interceptor, which performs logging. Nothing actually edits the code in class `A` to intercept, perform logging, etc. Since said code calls methods in the same `A` class, ie `this`, the interceptor you've injected into the `IWorker` call is never touched during those nested calls.

To observe this, try printing `worker.GetType()` (or observing the type in a debugger) and note that it will *not* be of type `A`.

This can be an example of the Single Responsibility Principle, in that your interface implementations should not be calling things on the `this` object because it can break down logging and unit testing. If you can't digest your solution into separate interfaces, you might consider making your implementation request a property of the same interface type and calling on *that*.